# Xamarin or Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: xamarin

can anybody explain which tools I need. I have downloaded Xamarin studio but is this now merged into Visual studio for Mac ? I don't understand the difference.

Can you actually use both IDEs or what's going on. ? It seems that the trial licence I have in Xamarin is actually for VS...!

Comment: VSMac is basically a rebranded XS.  Functionally they should be equivalent.  Moving forward I would expect VS to eventually replace XS.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin Studio sharing the same base. You can say if you will that Xamarin Studio is the father of Visual Studio for Mac. They are equal when it comes to mobile development. But Visual Studio for Mac brings support for asp.net core and has a higher Azure integration as well.

Comment: thanks everyone for explaining some of it. Then I'am really confused about the licensing. I have now an enterprise trail license. When that expires do I then need to buy a license to develop IOS apps. ? It seem that the community edition of XS is limited. Any comments ?

Answer (score 1):

[Xamarin Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/) is a stable release, whereas Visual Studio for Mac is in [preview](https://developer.xamarin.com/visual-studio-mac/). The [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs-mac/preview/vs-mac-preview1/) highlight new features, such as .NET Core support, connected app templates, and multi-process debugging. Visual Studio for Mac can be installed side-by-side with Xamarin Studio and [requires Mono 4.8](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs-mac/preview/vs-mac-preview1/#Side_by_Side_Installation_with_Xamarin_Studio), which is available in the alpha and beta channels. Currently, installing the stable version of Xamarin Studio will downgrade Mono to an older version; this can be worked around by switching Xamarin Studio to alpha or beta, or opting out of the Mono downgrade.